# How to trigger (change) on select option when the component loads

Tags: angular

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" class="custom-select">
  <option value="Running">Running</option>
  <option value="Paused">Paused</option>
</select>
```

This gets the value of the option when the option value changes but I also what that when the component loads then `onChange` method should trigger and bring the value of the currently selected option which is the first value

```
onChange(selectedStatus: string) {
  console.log(selectedStatus);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to do that? Standard html `selected` should do it, or use `ngModel`

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use ngModel like this:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" class="custom-select">
```

and in your *.ts file:

```
selectedValue="Running";
```

but if you insist on using the event, you can use **ngAfterViewInit** like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit{
  this.onChange("Running");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTMLElement on angular and fire change event

```
   let element:HTMLElement=document.getElementById('') as HTMLElement;
    element.onchange(undefined);
```